# Showing $\mathrm{Var}(\min(X,y))$ is increasing in $y$ where $X$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

For nonnegative random variables, expectation is defined to be the supremum of all expectations of simple random variables $A$ that satisfy $A\leq X$. (For  simple random variables, $E(A)=\sum_jc_jP(C_j)$ where $c_j$'s are nonnegative constants and $C_j$'s are disjoint events in $\Omega$.)

Let $X$ be a nonnegative real-valued random variable, how can we show that  $\mathrm{Var}(\min(X,y))$ is increasing in $y$? ($y$ is a constant.)

I thought that the proof is probably based on definition of expectation and I would need compare $\mathrm{Var}(\min(X,y_1))$ and $\mathrm{Var}(\min(X,y_2))$ for $y_1\leq y_2$ and probably start from some simple RVs.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If $X$ were continuous, you could define $Z=\min[X,y]$ and write $Var(Z) = \int_0^{\infty}P[Z^2>t]dt - (\int_0^{\infty} P[Z>t]dt)^2$ and take a derivative with respect to $y$, the derivative existing for continuous random variables.  Of course you need to replace "increasing" with "nondecreasing."

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint from @Michael:

$Var(min(X,y))$
= $Var(Z)$
= $\int_0^{\infty} P[Z^2 > t] dt - (\int_0^{\infty} P[Z > t] dt)^2$
= $\int_0^{\infty} P[min(X,y)^2 > t] dt - (\int_0^{\infty} P[min(X,y) > t] dt)^2$
= $\int_0^{y^2} P[X^2 > t] dt - (\int_0^{y} P[X > t] dt)^2$

Then,
$\frac{d}{dy}[Var(min(X,y))]$
= $ 2y P[X^2 > y^2] - 2 (\int_0^{y} P[X > t] dt) P[X > y]$
= $ 2y P[X > y] - 2 (\int_0^{y} P[X > t] dt) P[X > y]$
= $ 2 P[X > y] (y - \int_0^{y} P[X > t] dt)$
$\geq 0$

with the last line following from $\int_0^{y} P[X > t] dt \leq \int_0^{y} dt = y$

The inequality must be weak because, if $X$ were a constant then $\forall y: Var(min(X,y)) = 0$ so $Var(min(X,y))$ does not increase in $y$.